# swift 3 can't update markerinfowindow content after call API

Tags: google-maps, swift3

I am using this code to return an GoogleMarkerInfoWindow, and it works fine!

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customInfoWindown", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindowns
        customInfoWindow.title = "This is title"
        return customInfoWindow
}
```

but when I update the title after call an API, then I can't update this label

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customInfoWindown", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindowns
        let id = marker.userData as? String 
        UserManager.sharedInstance.getUserInfo(id, onComplete: {(content, error) in
            let userModel = UserModel.convertStringToUserModel(content!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {                
                 customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name // this code didn't work
            }
        } )            
        return customInfoWindow
}
```

How can I do to update this label after call API?

Thank you!

Comment: Try once updating you UI on main thread, in swift 3 it is `DispatchQueue.main.async {  customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name }`

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name }
I have a try but it didn't work.

Comment: `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {return marker}`
this method auto call by GoogleMap lib after clicked on the marker, so I can't handle every things before this method is called.

Comment: From where you getting `id` that you are using to call `API`?

Comment: `let id = marker.userData as? String`, when I crete a marker, then I save this Id by : `marker.userData = "my_id"` , `marker.userData` are supported by GoogleMap lib

Comment: Ok try to put break point in line `customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name` and check it is executing or not.

Comment: `customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name ` , yes, this line executed

Comment: Are you still updating `UI` main thread, right? Also check `userModel.name` is not empty.

Comment: yes,  `userModel.name` is not empty, and I updated this label on UI main thread too -> nothing changed on UI.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `async` try to reload map view

```
self.map.reloadInputViews()
```

Comment: Have you added DispatchQueue.main.async { self.map.reloadInputViews()  customInfoWindow.title = userModel.name } inside your `Alamofire` block ?

Comment: Maybe you've done it already but have you tried to print out the `userModel.name` ? to see whether you are getting it or not ?

Comment: yes, `userModel.name` always return a not empty value.